# Does the Sinaiticus contain the name of Jesus?

Tags: jesus, manuscript, nomina-sacra

In the Sinaiticus manuscript I see the name ⲒⲨ which is taken to be ΙΗΣΟΥ in abbreviation at the beginning of Mark's gospel.

Where is the name of Jesus actually written out in full anywhere in the manuscript?

Comment: Almost none of the majuscule MSS use the sacred names in full but only nomina sacra abbreviations.  Sinaiticus is no different.

Answer (score 2):

There are 907 instances of ⲓⲏⲥⲟⲩⲥ in Codex Sinaiticus.

Of these there are three occurrences of the name written out *plene*:

- Mark 16:6:  ⲓ̈ⲏⲥⲟⲩⲛ
- Luke 3:29 ⲓ̈ⲏⲥⲟⲩ. (referring to Joshua)
- Col. 4:11 ⲓ̈ⲏⲥⲟⲩⲥ (Jesus called Justus)

So, in the entire NT corpus of Sinaiticus, it looks like there's only one time ⲓⲏⲥⲟⲩⲥ is written out *plene* (Mark 16:6).

Comment: ... [τον ναζαρηνον omitted] ουκ εϲτιν ωδε ... doesn't say "of Nazareth", does say, "he is not here"